# undeclared identifier Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(specId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);

Tags: solidity, remix, chainlink

undeclared identifier

copied contract from link docs https://docs.chain.link/docs/jobs/types/direct-request/

```
import "https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol";
contract MyClient is ChainlinkClient {
    function doRequest(uint256 _payment) public {
        Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(specId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
        req.add("fetchURL", "https://datafeed.xyz/eth");
        req.add("jsonPath", "data,result");
        sendChainlinkRequest(req, _payment);
    }

    function fulfill(bytes32 requestID, uint256 answer) public {
        // ...
    }
}
```

trying to make a simple http get request to my API/URL https://ljiigsoedk.execute-api.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/default/wildfire..

but without modifying any code i get undeclared identifier Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(specId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector); with >>specID<< being pointed at by angry remix compiler

my nodes job is

```
type = "directrequest"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "example eth request event spec"
contractAddress = "0xCcbB32b820799DDCadCFeEE472B9804a1397005E"
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
observationSource = """
    ds          [type="http" method=GET url="https://ljiigsoedk.execute-api.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/default/wildfire"]
    ds_parse    [type="jsonparse" path="FIRE_NUMBE"]
    

    ds -> ds_parse 
"""
externalJobID = "37ab8f92-090e-4d23-9b08-96495f96899f"
```

haven't made it that far yet, im guessing i am following the right steps for making this happen.. if not please let me know what i am doing wrong..

or is this blob what i should use for the job -.-

```
// First, we parse the request log and the CBOR payload inside of it
decode_log  [type="ethabidecodelog"
             data="$(jobRun.logData)"
             topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"
             abi="SomeContractEvent(bytes32 requestID, bytes cborPayload)"]

decode_cbor [type="cborparse"
             data="$(decode_log.cborPayload)"]

// Then, we use the decoded request parameters to make an HTTP fetch
fetch [type="http" method=GET url="$(decode_cbor.fetchURL)"]
parse [type="jsonparse" path="$(decode_cbor.jsonPath)" data="$(fetch)"]

// Finally, we send a response on-chain.
// Note that single-word responses automatically populate
// the requestId.
encode_response [type="ethabiencode"
                 abi="(uint256 data)"
                 data="{\\"data\\": $(parse) }"]

encode_tx       [type="ethabiencode"
                 abi="fulfillOracleRequest(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes32 data)"
                 data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_mwr)}"
                 ]

submit_tx  [type="ethtx" to="0x613a38AC1659769640aaE063C651F48E0250454C" data="$(encode_tx)"]

decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> encode_response -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
```

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that one of your typings is wrong. You'll need a `bytes32` for `specId` for example. Add next lines to your contract code above `doRequest` function

```js
using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

address private oracle;
bytes32 private specId;
uint256 private fee;

constructor() {
   setPublicChainlinkToken();
   oracle = 0xCcbB32b820799DDCadCFeEE472B9804a1397005E; // oracle address from posted job, replace if different
   specId = "37ab8f92090e4d239b0896495f96899f"; // jobId from posted job, replace if different
   fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // your fee goes here, this is default value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for [buildChainlinkRequest](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-framework/#buildchainlinkrequest) the first parameter is a `bytes32`.

There's an example in the documentation

```
bytes32 jobId = "493610cff14346f786f88ed791ab7704";
```

Comment: yep you're right, specId is the jobId passed as a string